# Getting NameError with code using attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, inheritance, attr-accessor

This is code to generate moves by each pawn in the game of chess from a particular position.

```
class Characters
    def initialize(behaviours)
        @position=behaviours.fetch(:assigning_position)
        @right=behaviours.fetch(:moving_right)

    end
    def perform_position
        @position.kmoves
    end
    def perform_right
        @right.rightmove
    end
  end
```

this is the method for assigning position for a particular pawn.

```
class Position
    def kmoves
        print "enter x value"
        xpos=STDIN.gets.chomp
        print "enter y value"
        ypos=STDIN.gets.chomp
        print "#{xpos}, #{ypos}\n"
    end
end
```

this is the method to move pawn by one position to its right

```
class Right_move < Position
    def rightmove
        puts "compute right moves"
        xpos+=1
    end
end

king = Characters.new( assigning_position:Position.new,moving_right:Right_move.new)
king.perform_position
king.perform_right
```

I get the error:

> in `kmoves': undefined local variable or method`xpos' for # (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've included your attr_accessors in the `Characters` class instead of the `Position` class. There's also a typo in your placement of the colon. Try this:

```
class Position
    attr_accessor :xpos, :ypos

    def kmoves
        print "enter x value"
        xpos = STDIN.gets.chomp
        print "enter y value"
        ypos = STDIN.gets.chomp
        print "#{xpos}, #{ypos}\n"
    end
end
```

Also, you might want to rename your `Characters` class to `Character` because it appears to represent an individual character rather than a collection of them.

Comment: i am actually trying to create a common methods for moves such as right,left diagonals etc.and il implement a rake file where in ill call each of these methods in for loop depending upon the pawns.

Comment: in `rightmove': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError